# Redundant DS segment override prefix inserted by nasm?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, disassembly

I am working on a x86 disassembler for educational purposes. I have been using nasm for assembling different instructions.

Currently I am looking into the 16-bit addressing forms with the ModR/M byte. The "Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developers Manual: Volume 2A Instruction Set Reference, A-M" (I think my version is outdated but this information should still hold true) states that "The default segment register is SS for the effective addresses containing a BP index, DS for other effective addresses".

So if I understand this correctly, the following instructions should do exactly the same:

```
mov [bx], eax
mov [ds:bx], eax
```

However, when I compile the above instructions using nasm and look at the bytes generated, I get the following:

```
67 89 07      mov [bx], eax
3e 67 89 07   mov [ds:bx], eax
```

I understand the meaning of all the bytes, but I do not understand why nasm would add a ds segment override prefix (3e) to the second instruction. It seems unnecessary to me since ds already is the default segment.

My question is: am I missing something here or is the ds segment override prefix not needed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you typed in `mov [ds:bx], eax` the assembler should assemble `mov [ds:bx], eax`. NASM is not (and should not!) an optimizing assembler which corrects your inputs. Maybe you exactly need space of four bytes for modifying the program code.

Comment: It does optimize immediate constants and relative addresses though, but I take your point for explicit prefixes

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that "mov [ds:bx], eax" should have exactly the same meaning as "mov [bx], eax" because the "ds:" part is default. Or I am not reading the manual correctly. So this comment is not really useful since my question has very little to do with optimization.

Comment: @ArnoKalkman: No, if you write `mov [ds:bx], eax`, it has **not** the same "meaning" as `mov [bx], eax`. In the first case you tell the assembler "take `DS`!", in the other case you tell the assembler "take nothing, CPU default is ok!". The both instructions have in fact the same effect, but not the same machine code.

Comment: And "CPU default" is DS, right? (so in case of "DS:[....]" this would always be unnecessary and only needed for other segment registers, no?)

Comment: @DADi590 It is DS by default, but that doesn't mean it's always unnecessary. Perhaps you need the padding, or you're doing some tricky code obfuscation and you'll use the extra 3e byte for something else later.